# Browser not sending username with request in HTTP headers

Tags: iis, http, http-headers, google-chrome

I'm facing an issue where the browser is not sending the username with the request headers in my web application. I've tried using Google chrome and Edge for testing purposes.

I have observed this problem specifically with the following request:

> Method: GET
> URL: /AcimProxy/v1/results/e347969bbcf23c1ad009da6227560f85958ee441

In the log, the username is not included in the request headers, and as a result, I'm getting a 401 (Unauthorized) response from the server.

I have verified that the username is correctly provided when logging in, and it works as expected in other scenarios. However, for this particular request, the browser seems to omit the username from the headers. The other API endpoints are working just fine.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on why this issue might be occurring and how I can resolve it. Additionally, if there are any specific browser configurations or headers that I need to check or modify to ensure the username is sent with the request, please let me know.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: The browser will only send back a username where the server specifies a realm and has previously responded with a 401. Provide examples of the (FULL!) request/response headers for a login request and for a subsequent request missing the credentials (redact the values the credentials)